# Monitor/Mwait not working in kernel space

Tags: kernel

I want to test if monitor/mwait works in kernel. So I create a module, inside which two tasks are launched, task2 would call monitor/mwait to sleep. Task1 modify the armed address to wake up task2. But the code seems doesn't work. The mwait just act like NOP. I check the availability of monitor/mwait by using cpu_has function and my processor does support it.

Could you give me some hint or some sample code on how to use monitor/mwait in kernel space?

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <asm/mwait.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/tty.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <asm/desc.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>

/* global varaible */
char msg[200];
struct task_struct *task1;
struct task_struct *task2;
unsigned int addr = 0;

/* print message to console */
int write_console (char *str)
{
         struct tty_struct *my_tty;
         if((my_tty=current->signal->tty) != NULL)
         {
                ((my_tty->driver->ops->write) (my_tty,str,strlen(str)));
                return 0;
         }
         else return -1;
}

int thread_func1(void *data)
{
    msleep(5000);
    addr = 1;
    while(!kthread_should_stop()){
        schedule();
    }
    return 0;
}

int thread_func2(void *data)
{
    while(addr == 0){
        clflush(&addr);
        __monitor(&addr, 0, 0);
        if(addr == 0){
            __mwait(0,0);
            printk(KERN_INFO "wake up\n");
        }
    }

    while(!kthread_should_stop()){
        schedule();
    }
    return 0;
}

int __init my_test_init(void){
    struct cpuinfo_x86 *c = &boot_cpu_data;
    write_console("enter module\r\n");
    if (cpu_has(c, X86_FEATURE_MWAIT)) {
        write_console("monitor/mwait supported\r\n");
    }
    task1 = kthread_create(&thread_func1, NULL, "thread_func1");
    task2 = kthread_create(&thread_func2, NULL, "thread_func2");
    if(task1){ wake_up_process(task1); }
    if(task2){ wake_up_process(task2); }

    return 0;
}

void __exit my_test_exit(void){
    kthread_stop(task1);
    kthread_stop(task2);
    write_console("leave \r\n");
}

module_init(my_test_init);
module_exit(my_test_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```